# Bidirectional mapping using just ID on one side

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, bidirectional

I have two classes, Parent and Children

```
@Entity
class Parent {

     @Id 
     private long id;

     @OneToMany
     private List<Children> children;

}

@Entity
class Children {

      @Id
      private int id;

      @ManyToOne
      private Parent parent; //Normal bi-directional mapping
                   // OR 
      private long parentId; //just keeping reference to parent (kind of bi-directional)
}
```

Requirements

I do need navigational access in both directions. But navigational access from child to parent is not critical. It will be used once in a while to do some operations. The navigational access from parent to child is very important at the application layer and part of core business logic.

1. Does keeping bi-directional mapping makes sense at all here?
2. If yes, then does keeping just the id of parent in the child makes sense? I am afraid about the complexities that I might run into if I map the entire parent entity to the child.

As I understand, mapping the entity or just the Id of parent is not going to make any difference in the database storage as in both the cases the database will keep only one column for it (as foreign key in case of mapping entity, and as a normal column-parentId in case of keeping just the id).

However, I might gain some performance if I inform the database explicitly about the bidirectional relationship between the two entities?

***PS:*** Ignore the missing annotations and other parameters to complete the mapping syntactically. The question is not about 'How should I' but 'Should I'?

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do with Hibernate is:

Child.class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

i.e., you join only on the id, but store the whole parent object, respectively

Parent.class

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Children> children = new ArrayList<Children>();
```

To answer your first question: Yes, bidirectional mapping makes sense, because there is a connection obviously.

Edit: Although the mapping is not perfect, because children usually don't have one parent, but two. ;)